# Relative search in Mysql

Tags: mysql

In my database I have a record with title is "Học lập trình hướng đối tượng với Java"

When I search I use  `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title like '%hoc%'`

Or `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title like '%Học%'`

But it doesn't work

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the collation of the column that saves the title?

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title = 'Học lập trình hướng đối tượng với Java';` works?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the character `ọ` in the database and the character `ọ` which you have used in the query are different even though they looks same.

The original character in the database is a combination of two characters, `Latin small letter o (U+006F)` and a `Combining Dot Below ̣  (U+0323)` character to form `ọ`. On the other hand, what you have used in the query is a single character, `Latin Small Letter O With Dot Below ọ (U+1ECD)`.

You can fix the issue by using the same combination of characters as of the database:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title like '%Học%'
```

or you can use `_` or `%` to skip unknown characters:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title like '%H__c%'
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title like '%H%c%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `like` operator is **case-sensitive**, so if the case of the text you are searching for does not match the case of the text in the `post_title` column, the search will not return any results. You can use the `LOWER()` or `UPPER()` function to convert the text in the `post_title` column to **lowercase** or **uppercase**, respectively, before performing the search. For example:

```
select * from posts WHERE UPPER(post_title) like '%HỌC%';
```

OR

```
select * from posts WHERE LOWER(post_title) like '%học%';
```

OR

```
select * from posts WHERE post_title like '%Học%';
```

**Working Demo:** https://dbfiddle.uk/-fJrbLMk